# typedef memory allocation

Tags: c, variables

VARIABLES AREN'T SET IN STONE YET! Excuse if if no indention. I am new to this site. Anyway, I have a text document of a list of games in five different categories, and I need to some help with memory allocation VIA typedef. How would one do it? So far, this is what I have:

```
/* 
Example of text document

2012 DotA PC 0.00 10
2011 Gran Turismo 5 PS3 60.00 12
list continues in similar fashion...
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//function prototype here

char **readFile(char *file);
char *allocateString(char temp[]);

typedef struct
{
    int year;
    char name[100];
    char system[10];
    float price;
    int players;
}game;


int main(void)
{
char **list;

system("pause");
return 0;
}

//function defined here
char **readFile(char *file) //reads file and and allocates
{ 
FILE* fpIn;
    int i, total=0;


    fpIn = fopen("list.txt", "r");
    if (!fpIn)
    {
        printf("File does not exist");
        exit(101);
    }

/*
allocate memory by row here VIA for loop with the total++ to keep track of the 
number of games
*/
/*
allocate memory individually for each item VIA "allocateString by using going 
to set list[i] = allocateStrng(tmpList) using for loop the for loop will have
for (i=0; i<total; i++)
*/

return;
}

//allocateString here
char *allocateString(char temp[]);
{
char *s;

s = (char*)calloc(strlen(temp+1), sizeof(char)));
strcpy(s, temp);

return s;
}
```

Comment: You could `calloc` an array of pointers, and then `calloc` individually each pointer element.

Comment: temp+1 inside the calloc call is pointer artithmatic - probably not what you intended.

Comment: Do you want to allocate memory for the `game` typedef? It works just as a normal "type", so can be used in calls to e.g. `calloc` as ususe: `game *games = calloc(10, sizeof(game));`

Comment: well, you could not abuse typedef as a means to avoid typing "struct", to begin with

Answer (score 2):

Usually you'd allocate a decent amount of memory up front, detect situations where that amount is not enough, and enlarge the allocation in those cases using [`realloc`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Changing-Block-Size.html) (or [`malloc`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Basic-Allocation.html) followed by [`memcpy`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Copying-and-Concatenation.html) and [`free`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Freeing-after-Malloc.html)). This advice holds for both the buffer into which you read the current line (to be passed as `temp` to `allocateString`) and the array to hold the sequence of all lines.

You can detect an insufficient buffer size for the line buffer when after calling [`fgets(buf, bufsize, fpIn)`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html) the `strlen(buf) == bufsize - 1` but still `buf[bufsize - 2] != '\n'`. In other words, when reading filled the whole buffer, but still didn't reach a newline. In that case, the next read will continue the current line. You might want an inner loop to extend the buffer and read again for as long as it takes.

Note that your `allocateString` pretty much duplicates [`strdup`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Copying-and-Concatenation.html#index-strdup-499), so you might want to use that instead.

The links in the above text mainly come from the [manual of the GNU C library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/index.html). [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) is another good source of C function documentation. As are [the Linux man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/3/).

Comment: Sorry, but the memory allocation I'm familiar with is calloc. As for strdup, I haven't learned that yet. In the end goal, I'm supposed to create a program which does what I need to do with no memory leaks.

Comment: @AlexanderHuang: The main difference between `alloc` and `calloc` is that the latter will zero the memory. As `alloc` only takes a single size argument, one must usually multiply the count by the `sizeof` manually, but as `sizeof(char) == 1` specifying the count is enough here. If this is a [homework](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/188688) assignment, please add the `homework` tag to it. I'll add some pointers to docs to my answer.

Comment: Ah. Thanks then, it is a homework assignment. Again, sorry. New to this site.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = (char*)calloc(strlen(temp+1), sizeof(char)));

//the name of the array is a pointer, so you are doing pointer arithmetic.  
//I think you want strlen(*temp+1, sizeof(char)));
 // or strlen(temmp[1]) it isn't clear if this is a pointer to a string or an array 
 // of strings
//you need the length of the string *temp is the content which temp points to

//strcpy(s, temp);
```

Comment: The variables aren't set in stone yet. I just need like an example code to figure out to memory allocate the code first into rows and then by each item. If there is an easier way to allocate memory first by row and then by column in an easier way by using less pointers. It would be awesome.

Comment: Please use the formatting buttons on to of the edit pane to format your answer appropriately.

Comment: Don't cast the return of `calloc`, in C you can assign from `void*` to any other pointer without problems. And doing such casts may hide problems. Also `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition, this is actually how `sizeof` is defined, in relation to the size of the `char` type.

Comment: I had copied the code posted by the inquiring user.  It was an attempt to help him with his pointers.  I myself do not use calloc.  I believe in calloc you can use the sting lenth and must give the the type.  So the size will not be 1 character it will be 1 character for each charcater in the string.